# Why don't I get the same result as with tensorflow's method when I write my own expression?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, logistic-regression, cross-entropy

I'm learning logistic regression and I want to calculate what is the value of the cross entropy loss function during minimizing it via gradient descent, but when I use tensorflow's sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits function, I get different result from what I get via my own expression.

Here is an example:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

pred = np.array([[0.2],[0.3],[0.4]])
test_y = np.array([[0.5],[0.6],[0.7]])
print(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits = pred, labels = test_y))
print(-test_y * tf.math.log(pred) - (1-test_y) * tf.math.log(1-pred))
```

The output:

```
tf.Tensor(
[[0.69813887]
 [0.67435524]
 [0.63301525]], shape=(3, 1), dtype=float64)
tf.Tensor(
[[0.91629073]
 [0.86505366]
 [0.7946512 ]], shape=(3, 1), dtype=float64)
```

Can anyone explain to me what's wrong with this? I checked the tensorflow documentation about their function, and it seems like it should be doing exactly the same as my expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to take the sigmoid of your predictions `pred` before computing the cross entropy loss:

```py
-test_y * tf.math.log(tf.math.sigmoid(pred)) - (1-test_y) * tf.math.log(1-tf.math.sigmoid(pred))
```

```
tf.Tensor(
[[0.69813887]
 [0.67435524]
 [0.63301525]], shape=(3, 1), dtype=float64)
```